# Can't set CSS with jQuery for <td> in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('.top:last-child').css({'color':'red'});
```

To prove that the selector works I tried:

```
$('.top:last-child').hide();
```

And it was working.

Here is the html code

```
<table class="topMenu" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="top"  id="tm_active" >
    <a href="http://www.********/member.php"   class="top_link"><span class="down" style="font-weight:normal;">Startpagina</span>
    <!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <div style="position:relative;display:block;"></div>
</td><td class="top"  >
    <a href="http://www.******/"   class="top_link"><span class="down" style="font-weight:normal;">Mijn Profiel</span>
    <!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <div style="position:relative;display:block;"></div>
</td><td class="top"  >
    <a href="http://www.******/search.php?show=match"   class="top_link"><span class="down" >Matches</span>
    <!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <div style="position:relative;display:block;"></div>
</td><td class="top"  >
    <a href="http://www.*******/mail.php?mode=inbox"   class="top_link"><span class="down" style="font-weight:normal;">Berichten</span>
    <!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <div style="position:relative;display:block;"></div>
</td><td class="top"  >
    <a href="http://www.**********//"   class="top_link"><span class="down" >`</span>
    <!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <div style="position:relative;display:block;">  <!--[if lte IE 6]><table id="mmm"><tr><td><![endif]-->

    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></div>
</td></tr></table>
```

It works perfectly over Firefox and Opera.
**Issue** : remains but solved with a work around

Comment: Show your whole HTML table markup. It might be that you have invalid HTML.

Comment: even though it is all correct but , i'll do it any way

Comment: css `color:red` applies to the text, do you have any text content in last `<td>`?

Comment: your code is working fine in ie : http://jsfiddle.net/fM4dT/

Comment: @YogeshWaran i know and that's whats driving me crazy

Comment: @Neverever this is just to make the point i'll edit and just make the full case

Comment: @user1743214: please provide more information

Comment: @YogeshWaran well ,im really not sure about it lol , but it just wont add the style attribute to the `<TD>` but any other function (as far as i have tried ) works so it's not the selector it's some thing else ...
i tried `.attr("stye","mystyle")`

Comment: again please the problem isnt in the selector ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue you use in css code and dont use jquery

```
.top:last-child{
  color:red;
}
```

best regards

Comment: frankly your answer should have been the logical choice for me , and it is . it works perfectly. thanks for the tip ,i guess, but i'll leave the question opened cuz i really want to know whats the issue ... again thanks

Comment: can i see your css code,i guess your css code is wrong that jquery dont work

Answer (score 1):

The ":last-child"-selector isn't supported by all versions of ie. Try to use the ".last()" method instead:

```
$('.top').last().css({'color':'red'});
```

Comment: actually it does , and i tried your suggestion before and it didnt work .. thanks for the answer :)

Comment: can i see your css code,i guess your css code is wrong that jquery dont work